# How to access object(readonly)'s property in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

For example:

```
// ClassA.h
#import "ClassB.h"
@interface ClassA : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) ClassB *classB;
@end

// ClassB.h
@interface ClassB : NSObject
@property (assign) CGFloat someProperty;
@end

// main.m
#import "ClassA.h"
...
ClassA *classA = [ClassA new];
classA.classB.someProperty
...
```

I want to access `someProperty` like `classA.classB.someProperty` in `main.m`, so I have to import `ClassB.h` in `ClassA` header file. But I just want to access ClassB's properties or methods in `main.m`, I want to forbid user to create a **ClassB** object in `main.m`.
What should I do?

```
// main.m
classA.classB.someProperty --> ok
ClassB *classB = [ClassB new] --> forbid
```

Comment: Why not just create ClassB directly in `main.m`, like `[ClassB new]`? If you need to `ClassA`'s `ClassB` property, u must import ClassA as well.

Comment: @dirtydanee, refer to his code, the `classB` is `classA`'s property.

Comment: @dirtydanee, but I want to forbid user to create ClassA's objects in `main.m`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get `classB`'s property though `classA`, you must import `ClassA`.

**Edit**

If you do not want to create `classB` in `main.m`, you should in your `classA.m` import `ClassB.h` not in `classA.h`.

**Demo**

I create 2 controller class: `ViewController` and `ViewController2`:

In ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
// Forward declare ViewController2, instead of importing it.
// This way it will be visible for your header file, but will get error if trying to create a instance of it
@class ViewController2;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) ViewController2 *vc2;

@end
```

In ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
}

@end
```

Comment: But I also could create ClassB's objects in `main.m`, I want to forbid it.

Comment: @afishhhhh, forbid what ? firbid `create a ClassA object in main.m` ? then you want to use the `classA`'s property(`classB`)? it is conflictive.

Comment: forbid `create a ClassB object in main.m`

Comment: @afishhhhh you should in your classA.m import ClassB. not in classA.h

Comment: if I import ClassB.h in ClassA.m, I could not access `classA.classB.someProperty` in `main.m`

Comment: @afishhhhh, see my `demo`, I edited my answer, use `@class` to promote the classB

Answer (score 0):

```
- (instancetype)init NS_UNAVAILABLE;
```

You can add `NS_UNAVAILABLE` attributed to the `init` method of `ClassB` in that way, you will not be able to call,

```
ClassB *classB = [ClassB new];
```

Comment: this will prevent `ClassB` to be initialised all over the application using the `[ClassB new]` or `[ClassB alloc] init]`, not just in `main.m`.